# Error: Every derived table must have its own alias

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datediff

```
UPDATE `FlightSchedule`
SET delay=(
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT
      MINUTE(ETA - STA)
    FROM `FlightSchedule`
      WHERE `flightNum_arr` = '3517'
  )
)
WHERE `flightNum_arr` = '3517';
```

Says:

> "Every derived table must have its own alias".

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixing it - exactly like it was shown in your error message:

```
UPDATE `FlightSchedule` 
SET delay=
(SELECT update_field
 FROM 
 (
  SELECT MINUTE (ETA - STA) AS update_field
  FROM `FlightSchedule` 
  WHERE `flightNum_arr`='3517'
 ) AS internal_0
)
WHERE `flightNum_arr`='3517';
```

But actually above there more correct suggestion - get rid of that nested subquery at all (see Gordon's answer).

*Edit (based on comments)*:

If you want to find difference, use [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function:

```
UPDATE `FlightSchedule` 
    SET delay = TIMEDIFF(ETA - STA)
    WHERE `flightNum_arr`='3517';
```

Comment: +1 for such a nice explanation, lol :)

Comment: @ØHankyPankyØ - I think a lot of problems will be solved if people will not just notice error messages, but actually _read_ them and **understand** :p

Comment: Actually, the answer is syntactically incorrect, because the second alias is not needed and not appropriate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - yes, thanks (misplaced those brackets)

Comment: Now it says Truncated incorrect time value: '6100.000000'

Comment: @KlausosKlausos - that's a matter of logic, not a syntax.

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo: The goal is just to calculate the value of delay for a given field specified by `flightNum_arr`='3517'.

Comment: Now it says Truncated incorrect time value: '7400.000000'. The field delay is varchar. I don't understand why Minute(ETA-STA) provides 7400, though it must be equal to 7 minutes.

Comment: STA: 2013-08-26 20:30:00
ETA: 2013-08-26 21:04:00

Comment: @KlausosKlausos - see my edit for that issue

Comment: Based on your last update I came to the following solution: UPDATE `FlightSchedule` SET delay = MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(ETA, STA)) WHERE `flightNum_arr`='3729';

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the nested subquery.  But you don't even need it.  The right way to write this query is:

```
UPDATE `FlightSchedule` 
    SET delay = MINUTE(ETA - STA)
    WHERE `flightNum_arr`='3517';
```

Comment: You can't specify target table 'FlightSchedule' for update in FROM clause

Comment: @KlausosKlausos . . . Sorry, that was one step in my reasoning.

Comment: I need to use MINUTE (ETA - STA). Could you please tell me how to use it in your solution?